# Angular validate date

Tags: angular, date, validation

I have forms with dates (datepicker). Sometimes 2 dates.
I would like to set up validators but I can’t find anything.
I want to test and validate that the format of my date is correct
I want when I have 2 date that my end date is well after my start date

Namely that my application is in mutlilangue so several date format

I want when the user enters 22/48/22fr02ff or fr02020-15-8 that it displays a validation error because the date format is incorrect
I also want when 05/07/2020 is less than 20/06/2020 it displays a validation error because the first date is after the second

Example of input date:

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>DATE LABEL</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerDate" formControlName="myDate"
      autocomplete="off" placeholder="" />
    <mat-datepicker #pickerDate></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerDate">
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question isn't very clear but you either use a 3rd party datepicker like from ngx bootstrap

or

you write your own date input and validate it using angular reactive forms, formbuilder with your own validator

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#using-the-formbuilder-service-to-generate-controls

Comment: Help me ! I want to check that my date is in the correct format that the language of my application

Comment: this isn't really the place for a step by step guide.. you need to look at the material ui guide on how to do this ... https://material-ui.com/guides/localization/